# Is there any way to apply TDD techniques for dev in PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, unit-testing, plsql, tdd

As I have a lot of program logics in DB-server-side in PL/SQL I would like to find out is TDD applicable to PL/SQL. Even more it would be very god if you point me at some information resources that has samples and detailed description. Thanks in advance!

UPD: I need tests to be stored and runned only on my machine, doesn't affecting other team members. Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing for PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152441/unit-testing-for-pl-sql)

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is - just apply normal TDD cycle (see eg. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_driven_development)) as in any other programming language:

1. Add a test
2. Run all tests and see if the new one fails
3. Write some code
4. Run the automated tests and see them succeed
5. Refactor code
6. Repeat

You want to have a [unit testing framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#PL.2FSQL) of course. Unsuprisingly e.g. StackOverflow has questions like [Unit testing for PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152441/unit-testing-for-pl-sql) or [Unit Testing Framework for Oracle PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203376/unit-testing-framework-for-oracle-pl-sql). You've already checked those - haven't you ?

Running tests in isolation is very possible. You'll probably want to have either a dedicated Oracle DB instance or a schema that is 100% under your control.

The only tricky part I've experienced is to test a code that uses database very extensively or when database schema is changing a lot. Populating or faking a database might be tricky and time consuming if the database is complex or if a lot of data is required for test execution. I those cases I will usually fake the database by removing constraints and triggers that makes running tests cumbersome. That's fine because the focus is on a PL/SQL code, not on a database structure and unit testing is not the final verification step.

Comment: If the PL/SQL handles DML then disabling triggers, and to a lesser extent constraints, can create too many problems to compensate for a faster execution time.  But I agree that managing the test data is the hardest part of unit testing a database application.

Comment: @APC: That's true - it very much depends on the nature of the PL/SQL code and related DML. But that is something that have to be evaluated case by case - one has to find the right balance and level of unit testing. Ahem: [How to (unit-)test data intensive PL/SQL application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668094/how-to-unit-test-data-intensive-pl-sql-application)